# Bootstrap carousel next and previous button fail for some pop up modal in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, bootstrap-4, carousel

I have a Bootstrap Carousel to display groups of photos

There are groups of photos, each time I click on a photo in a group I display a Modal with all the photos in that particular group as a carousel with the clicked photo as the active one.
this works fine for the first group because I can click next and previous and move the carousel as expected
**BUT** for the other groups down the line it does not work
I get only the Modal pop up, with the active image and I can physically see that there are other photos in the group but the NEXT and PREVIOUS buttons don't work

Group of Photos

[image]

Component

```
import { areEqual } from 'Utils/equalityChecks';
import classes from './CustomReportEditor.module.css';
import { PhotoCarouselModal } from './PhotoCarouselModal';

interface Props {
  album: any;
  onPhotoClick: (e: any) => void;
}

const Albums = ({ album, onPhotoClick }: Props) => {
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
  const [currentPhotos, setCurrentPhotos] = useState([]);
  const [currentAlbumName, setCurrentAlbumName] = useState('');

  const onOpenCarousel = useCallback((index) => {
    setActiveIndex(index);
    setIsModalOpen(true);
  }, []);

// update
    const onNextPhoto = useCallback(() => {
        if (activeIndex === currentPhotos.length - 1) {
            setActiveIndex(0);
        } else {
            setActiveIndex((prev) => prev + 1);
        }
    }, [activeIndex, currentPhotos]);

    const onPrevPhoto = useCallback(() => {
        if (activeIndex === 0) {
            setActiveIndex((prev) => currentPhotos.length - 1);
        } else {
            setActiveIndex((prev) => prev - 1);
        }
    }, [activeIndex, currentPhotos]);
//>>>>>>> ends
  const onModalCloseClick = useCallback(() => {
    setIsModalOpen(false);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentPhotos(() => [...album.photos]);
    setCurrentAlbumName(album.name);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {}, [currentPhotos, currentAlbumName, activeIndex]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="">
        <ul className={classes.marginAuto}>
          <li className={`${classes.albumHead}`}>{album.name}</li>
        </ul>
        <ul className={`${classes.marginAuto}`}>
          {album?.photos?.length
            ? album?.photos?.map((_photo: any, index: number) => (
                <li key={`${index + 1}`} className={`${classes.albumPhotos}`}>
                  <button
                    className={classes.projectInfoListPhotoButton}
                    onClick={() => onOpenCarousel(index)}
                    onKeyDown={() => onOpenCarousel(index)}
                  >
                    Photo {index + 1}
                  </button>
                </li>
              ))
            : null}
        </ul>
      </div>
      <PhotoCarouselModal
        isOpen={isModalOpen}
        activeIndex={activeIndex}
        currentAlbumName={currentAlbumName}
        photos={currentPhotos}
        modalCloseClick={onModalCloseClick}
        onPhotoClick={onPhotoClick}
{/*UPDATE*/}
onNextPhoto={onNextPhoto}
                onPrevPhoto={onPrevPhoto}
      />
    </>
  );
};

const AlbumsMemo = memo(Albums, areEqual);

export { AlbumsMemo as Albums };
```

Carousel Modal

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';
import { areEqual } from 'Utils/equalityChecks';
import { PurpleButton } from 'Components/Button';
import { Modal } from 'Components/Modal';

import classes from './PhotoCarouselModal.module.css';

interface Props {
  isOpen: boolean;
  activeIndex: number;
  photos: any;
  currentAlbumName: string;
  modalCloseClick: (e: any) => void;
  onPhotoClick: (e: any) => void;
    onNextPhoto: () => void; //UPDATE
    onPrevPhoto: () => void;//UPDATE
}
const PhotoCarouselModal = ({
    isOpen,
    activeIndex,
    currentAlbumName,
    photos,
    modalCloseClick,
    onNextPhoto, //UPDATE
    onPrevPhoto, //UPDATE
}: Props) => (
  <Modal
    id="custom-report-photo-modal"
    classes={classes}
    title="Select Photo"
    isOpen={isOpen}
    modalHeader
    dataBsBackdrop="static"
    dataBsKeyboard="false"
    modalCloseClick={modalCloseClick}
  >
    <div id="carouselCaptions" className="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <div className="carousel-indicators">
        {photos.length
          ? photos.map((_: any, index: number) => (
              <button
                key={`${index + 1}`}
                type="button"
                data-bs-target="#carouselCaptions"
                data-bs-slide-to={index}
                className={`${activeIndex === index ? 'active' : ''}`}
                aria-current={activeIndex === index}
                aria-label={`${currentAlbumName} Photo ${index + 1}`}
              />
            ))
          : null}
      </div>

      <div className="carousel-inner">
        {photos.length
          ? photos.map((photo: any, index: number) => (
              <div key={`${index + 1}`} className={`carousel-item ${activeIndex === index ? 'active' : ''}`}>
                <img src={photo.raw} className={`d-block w-100 ${classes.carouselImage}`} alt="..." />
                <div className="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                  <h5 className={classes.carouselAlbumName}>
                    {currentAlbumName} Photo
                    {index + 1}
                  </h5>
                  <PurpleButton
                    className={classes.photoAddButton}
                    onKeyUp={() => {}}
                    onClick={() => onPhotoClick(photo.raw)}
                  >
                    Add Photo
                  </PurpleButton>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))
          : null}
      </div>

        <button
                        className="carousel-control-prev"
                        type="button"
                        data-bs-target="#carouselCaptions"
                        data-bs-slide="prev"
                        onClick={onPrevPhoto} //UPDATE
                    >
                        <span className="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true" />
                        <span className="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                    </button>
                    <button
                        className="carousel-control-next"
                        type="button"
                        data-bs-target="#carouselCaptions"
                        data-bs-slide="next"
                        onClick={onNextPhoto} //UPDATE
                    >
                        <span className="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true" />
                        <span className="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                    </button>
    </div>
  </Modal>
);

const PhotoCarouselModalMemo = memo(PhotoCarouselModal, areEqual);

export { PhotoCarouselModalMemo as PhotoCarouselModal };
```

UPDATE
LINK TO SANDBOX EXAMPLE
[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/photomodalcarousel-e7h42m?file=/src/index.tsx)

UPDATE

I fixed this problem by adding two custom callback functions for next and previous. Although it is not as smooth as the bootstrap slide animation
It does the job regardless.

Comment: You need to create an example in codesandbox, in this way there is too much unclear code

Comment: Alright, I will drop an example soon

Comment: I have updated the question with a sandBox example

Comment: I think I have been able to solve this problem

Comment: Side note: when you want to inform other people about your edits, don't forget to mention them like this @BenjaminAhunanya-Possible

Comment: oh! I will take note @niceman

Comment: @daza I updated with a solution

Comment: @BenjaminAhunanya-Possible good job! Just noticed you have some ts warnings because you set `any` as album type. I think the correct type there would be ```album: { name: string , photos: string[] }```

Comment: Alright @daza , I will update that

Answer (score 0):

The React components even though they are separated, when rendered they form a single page. That said, the "id" of the parent div of all modals are the same, only the first modal of the page works. You must provide a unique id for each parent div and that same id for "data-bs-target" of the prev and next buttons of each modal as well. Each modal must have its "id" and its "data-bs-target" buttons must use that reference id. I hope I was clear. If not, ask again here and I'll explain further. Do this and it will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).